# Exercise with solution in Algebric topology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation

Can anyone suggest a collection of (solved) exercises in Algebric topology? Undergrad level, as I want to study on my own and take an exam, I found some lecturenote but I need to see some example or exercise with solution. If you know a very good lecture note as well, I am so thankful to suggeste it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1) The book by Sergey V. Matveev

Lectures on Algebraic Topology, Sergey V. Matveev (EMS Series of Lectures in Mathematics, 2006)

contains about 10 pages of hints and solutions to its exercises.